# How to resize images in Xaringan presentation?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, xaringan

I'm trying to switch from ioslide to xaringan. I'm not able to properly resize a ggplot image to make full screen or al least to occupy as much space as possible. I'm using both `fig.height/width` and `out.height/width` arguments but only one dimension change. There is a better way to resize an image?
this is the setup:

````r
---
title: ""
author: ""
institute: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: 16:9
---
#```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina=2)

library(Cairo)
library(cairoDevice)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
#```

--- 

# Plot

#```{r echo=FALSE, out.height=450, out.width= 2000}
knitr::include_graphics("img/Rplot01.svg")
#```
````

And this is the result:
[image]

I would like to expand the image as much as possible

Comment: For option `out.width` and `out.height`, the input value needs to be a string. Try "100%" (with the quotes) instead.

Answer (score 14):

## To set the size of an image

You can use a markdown tag such as:

```
![:scale 50%](image.jpg)
```

see [this](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#34)

## As a background image:

In Xaringan you can add images like this:

```
---
class: inverse, center, middle
background-image: url(img/Rplot01.svg)
background-size: contain
```

Please check that the info within url is correct.

As a guide you can see [this presentation](https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/Presentations/spatial-analysis-presentation.html#9) (the link drives you to slide number 9, where is an image) generated using [this code](https://github.com/orlando-sabogal/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/blob/gh-pages/Presentations/spatial-analysis-presentation.Rmd) (see line 76)

Comment: Thanks @Orlando Sabogal for the answer. But I need to simply expand my image not using it as background. The problem is that I'm not able to use properly chunk options for resizing the image

Comment: I edited the answer. I think you can add it using markdown.

Comment: Adding it using the simple Markdown option you have noted: `[:scale 50%]`, did not work for me. Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the html `<img>` tag to resize and position an image in a Xaringan presentation slide.

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Sharingan_triple.svg"
     width="500px" height="500px"
     style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:130px;">
```